# Save plot from mirt inside a function

Tags: r, plot, lattice, r-base-graphics

I have a curious issue saving a plot generated inside a function when using the **mirt** package for R. Here's a reprex:

```
#save image from base plot
save_as_file = function(code, filename, width = 1000, height = 750) {
  png(filename, width = width, height = height)
  eval(substitute(code))
  dev.off()
  try(dev.off(), silent = T)
}

#test it
plot(1:3)
save_as_file(plot(1:3), "test.png")
#> null device 
#>           1
file.remove("test.png")
#> [1] TRUE
```

which makes this plot:

[image]

However, when I try to use this with **mirt**, nothing is produced:

```
#mirt test
library(mirt)
#> Loading required package: stats4
#> Loading required package: lattice
set.seed(1)
mirt_data = mirt::simdata(
  a = c(1:4),
  d = c(0,0,1,1),
  N = 1000,
  itemtype = "2PL"
)
mirt_fit = mirt(
  data = mirt_data,
  model = 1,
  itemtype = "2PL",
  verbose = F
)
plot(mirt_fit, type = "trace") #works
save_as_file(plot(mirt_fit, type = "trace"), "mirt.png") #nothing happens
#> null device 
#>           1
```

Producing this plot, but no file is saved. Why?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already found out, you mysteriously have to use `print`. The reason is that `plot(mirt_fit,...)` dispatches to `mirt:::plot_mixture(mirt_fit, ...)` which uses [`lattice`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lattice/index.html).

`lattice` functions behave differently from standard R graphics functions in that they do not immediately create a plot when executed. Instead, like conventional functions, they create an object of class `"trellis"`, and the plot is created using the print method `print.trellis` (ggplot has probably cribbed that). Therefore, it may be necessary to explicitly `print` (dispatches to `lattice:::print.trellis` in this case) the object to display the plot.

There is a slight problem with your proposed solution; if there's an error during plotting, it won't close the `png` device and will clutter your device list over time.

```
graphics.off()
dev.list()
# NULL
save_as_file(plot(stop(), type="trace"), "mirt.png")
# Error ...
save_as_file(plot(stop(), type="trace"), "mirt.png")
# Error ...
dev.list()
# png png 
#   2   3 
graphics.off()
```

So it's better to use `dev.off()` in `on.exit()`. Also we can use case handling, to avoid base R `plot`s to be `print`ed.

```
save_as_file <- function(code, filename, width=1000, height=750) {
  on.exit(dev.off())
  png(filename, width=width, height=height)
  p <- eval(substitute(code))
  if (!is.null(p)) print(p)
}

save_as_file(mirt:::plot_mixture(stop(), type="trace"), "mirt.png")
dev.list()  ## no device open
# NULL
save_as_file(plot(mirt_fit, type="trace"), "mirt.png")
save_as_file(plot(1:3), "mirt.png")
```

Comment: Good addition. I found that one has to use eval.parent() because otherwise one can get mysterious errors as the code was evaluated in a different environment.

Comment: @CoderGuy123 Interesting, we could edit the answer. How can we reproduce these errors?

Comment: I don't know how to make a reprex. I got the problem when calling plot() on a DIF test with mirt, and there's no easy way to reproduce that here because it relies on complicated functions of my own.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be simple. For some reason, one has to explicitly print the plot inside the function. This works:

```
#save image from base plot
save_as_file = function(code, filename, width = 1000, height = 750) {
  png(filename, width = width, height = height)
  print(eval.parent(substitute(code)))
  dev.off()
  try(dev.off(), silent = T)
}

save_as_file(plot(mirt_fit, type = "trace"), "mirt.png")
file.remove("mirt.png")
```